# I am getting [SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111] when trying to access AWS EC2 server from my flutter app

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, flutter, amazon-ec2, flutter-web

I cannot connect to the `REST API Server` running on a `AWS EC2` instance.

Below is the code snippet from the flutter application.

```
final EC2ServerPublicDNS = "http://ec2-*****.amazonaws.com";
final awsSigV4Client = new AwsSigV4Client(
        IAMUserAccessKey,
        IAMUserSecretKey,
        EC2ServerPublicDNS,
        region: region);
final signedRequest = new SigV4Request(
      awsSigV4Client,
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/test',
      headers:
          new Map<String, String>.from({"Content-Type": "application/json"}),
    );
    http.Response response;
    try {
      response =
          await http.get(signedRequest.url, headers: signedRequest.headers);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```

I am getting:

> [SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = ec2-*****.amazonaws.com, port = 33278]

Answer (score 0):

give permission of `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your android Manifest file.

Comment: This I did before